# Aggregating models "through" other models in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize based backend express API. In my sequelize models, a `Citizen` belongs to a `Street` which belongs to a `Town`, which belongs to a `State`. I can count the citizens in a `Street` easily like:

```
return db.Citizen.aggregate('value', 'count', {
    where: { 
         '$Town.name$': townName
    },
});
```

However, I would like to be able to count the citizens in a `Town` or `State`, even though Citizens aren't directly associated with those models. Is that possible and if so, how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is a nested include so you can connect all the models, something like this:

```
db.Citizen.count({
    include: [{
        model: db.Street,
        include : [{
          model: db.Town,
          where:{
            TownName : name
          }
        }]
      }]
  })
  .then(function(countCitizen) {
      return res.json(countCitizen);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {

  });
```

Comment: I am really after a solution that lets me use the aggregate function, as I need to do things like average age of `Citizens` etc.

Comment: Sequelize support aggregations on attributes http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#attributes. Hope this is what you need.